# parsing a file into a list of lists

Tags: python, parsing

I have text file in this manner

```
{ a 3 56 cd 8 }
{ 1 2 3 4 ab 546 }
```

I am currently using the following line to parse it into a list of list

```
for line in filename.readlines():
    line = line.lstrip('{').rstrip('}\n').strip(' ').split(' ')
```

Is this the best way to do this?
Because I have heard people say that the split function should be seldom used as it slows down the script considerably.

**EDIT:**
I expect the output to be:

```
[[a,3,56,'cd',8],[1,2,3,4,'ab',546]]
```

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of the output you want ? (Waht do you mean with list of lists) ?

Comment: have you measured this and seen that it will be a performance problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is no whitespace before the openening and after the closing bracket:

```
li = [line[1:-1].split() for line in file]
```

or if I can't assume that:

```
li = [line.strip()[1:-1].split() for line in file]
```

Comment: @Eknath lyer: I am. [1:-1] means "select every character except the first and last one". In other words: it ignores the brackets.

Comment: This code in vulnerable to a stray space in the end of the line. So, it's safer to use `strip()` in addition to `slicing`. And, as we still use `strip`, it's better to pack all the functionality in that `strip` function, thus avoiding one additional string object creation.

Comment: @ovgolovin: I agree with both of you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use a module like the `csv` module to parse your file. Here is a sample code.

```
# Your file contents - test.csv
{ 1 2 3 asd 4 5 6 }
{ 5 6 7 8 def 8 9 }

>>> import csv
>>> reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ')
>>> all_lines = []
>>> for line in reader:
>>>     # if the braces are always in the first and last positions
>>>     # you can just do this
>>>     all_lines.append(line[1:-1])
>>> 
>>> all_lines
[['1', '2', '3', 'asd', '4', '5', '6'], ['5', '6', '7', '8', 'def', '8', '9']]
```

Note that the list will contain the numbers as strings. You can convert them to numerical format before appending if you want to.

Comment: Why would you suggest I use the csv module here? It doesn't seem to have any apparent advantage.

Comment: You are right. In this specific case using a `csv` module is no better than directly reading the file. I was not sure how well behaved your input was going to be - for example say entries are going to be in quotes, separated with different delimiters etc. If it does, direct parsing will get complicated very soon and a `csv` module will make parsing more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension:

```
[ [ c for c in l.split() if c not in ('{', '}') ] for l in filename.readlines() ]
```

If you wish to avoid `split` you could use regex, don't know how this would perform better:

```
import re
[ re.findall("\w+", l) for l in filename.readlines() ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use one strip procedure:

```
L = []
for line in file:
    values = line.strip('{}\n\r ').split(' ')
    L.append(values)
```

It assumes your values don't have '{}'. It also would work on Windows (since the linebreak on Windows has \r apart from \n).

If several `split` functions are used, there are a lot of temporary objects created in the memory on each step (since `string` is immutable).

I doubt, if there is any faster solution other than using `split`.

Also, there is no need to clutter memory with the file with `filename.readlines()`. It can be perfectly read line by line using `for line in file`, also it's not OK to name `file_object` as `'file_name'`, since they are not exactly the same.

There are some solutions with `slicing` (`string[1:-1]`). Some testing is required to determine if this approach is faster than with only `strip` used.